# Failed to download Laravel/pint : composer gives a connection timeout error while downloading laravel/pint

Tags: php, laravel, curl, composer-php, laravel-sail

I wanted to create a new laravel project using sail , but it stops at `laravel/pint` and give me connection timeout error, the command is :

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/dashboard?with=mysql,redis,mailpit" | bash
```

the rror is :

```
// ...

- Downloading laravel/pint (v1.8.0)
      - Downloading fakerphp/faker (v1.21.0)
      - Downloading laravel/pint (v1.8.0)
      - Downloading laravel/framework (v10.7.1)
      - Downloading fakerphp/faker (v1.21.0)
      - Downloading laravel/pint (v1.8.0)
      - Downloading laravel/framework (v10.7.1)
      - Downloading phpunit/phpunit (10.0.19)
        Failed to download fakerphp/faker from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://codeload.github.com/FakerPHP/Faker/legacy.zip/92efad6a967f0b79c499705c69b662f738cc9e4d: Operation timed out after 300001 milliseconds with 722370 out of 3520622 bytes received
    Now trying to download from source
```

and at the end it fails

after couple tries, i tried to update one of my laravel 10 projects , but it also failed to install `laravel/pint`, when I remove it from my dev dependencies it works fine, all packages are ok except it,

Comment: Faker requires PHP >= 7.4. check if the "fakerphp/faker" is in "require-dev"

Comment: Remove your composer.lock. edit composer.json and remove fakerphp. `composer install`

Answer (score 2):

May be composer cache caused the problem.
What I did is:

**SOLUTION 1**

Run the following command

```
composer clear-cache
composer install
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Delete the vendor folder from your Laravel project

Then run the following command

```
composer clear-cache
composer install
```